# Reformating the partition where ownCloud files are stored. Recomendation?

Tags: linux, partitioning, python, ntfs

I'm having a small problem and I want to avoid an embarrassing situation if I screw up solving it.

My employer provides a customized ownCloud for shared storage. In my team, I am responsible for the administration of our portion of this shared drive. I set the local storage in my Linux system into a separate partition, and for a stupid reason, I formatted this as `exFAT`. Basically, for dual boot with Windows, I wanted to avoid Windows to block my shared partition, and `exFAT` was the recommended solution. This is no longer relevant, as I rarely boot into Windows and I know how to shut it down without locking any partition.

Fast-forward several months of usage and about 40GB of data is stored there. Now, my usage needs have changed, and I need to create a python virtual environment, so we can all share the same versions of python packages, and with the python to be deployed into VMs (not yet implemented). The issue is that `exFAT` does not support symbolic links. I know I can use `--always-copy` in the creation of the `venv`, but I kinda need symbolic links (Actually, I think I should use `--always-copy` to make the venv totally portable, but that's another story). I have some Python code that's also on that partition, and I use a symlink to the local package directory of Python (`~/.local/lib/python3.x/site-package`), so I can import them easily, and use autoreload in iPython. The `exFAT` put a constraint into this last functionality, which has become basic for me.

So, I decided to use `NTFS` instead of `exFAT` (I still need access to these partition during the infrequent Windows boots). Thus, for reformatting my shared partition, I wanted to copy the files to another location, reformat the `exFAT` into `NTFS`, and copy the files back. But that will change some fingerprint of the files, and might force updates into ALL the other users of the shared drive, including my manager/boss.

What's the best course of action? Of course, I don't want to lose any files, and I would like to reduce unnecessary traffic to the server and to the other users.

Any magic `cp`, `mv`, `rsync`, ... magic that might do the trick?

All advice are welcomed

**EDIT:** I reread my post and the best option is to delete to change the partition, and download the files from the server on my partition. That way, the files permissions are preserved, and I don't need to push any updates.

**EDIT #2:** What are the best option to mount a `NTFS` partition on `/etc/fstab`? I tried to set it with `ntfs-3g` but I get an error
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/nvme0n1p6': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/nvme0n1p6' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

If I set the `auto` option, it uses FUSE and everything is owned by `root` and the permissions are `777`

Comment: True conversion of exFAT to NTFS is impossible, so formatting is required with total data-loss. But it seems that you have found a good solution, so you don't need an answer from us.

Comment: Actually, I do. What are the best options to mount using `ntfs-3g`? I manage to mount using the `auto` option on fstab, which apparently defaults to FUSE, but I get all files owned by `root` and file permissions are `777`

Answer (score 0):

exFAT does not support user permissions, so the uid and gid
are whatever you specify in the mount command.
When mounted from `fstab` with the `auto` option, the device gets
automatically mounted with root-permissions.

The Proper options for exfat are described in the [mount.exfat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/mount.exfat.8.html) manpage.
An `/etc/fstab` entry could be similar to:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/maria/Lexfat exfat defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

The defaults options (rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async) are good enough. Your `uid` and `gid` can be obtained by the command
`id yourusername`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get rid of `exFAT` and use either `NTFS-3G` or the internal kernel support

Comment: I think your question could be simplified. As it's written, it's somewhat misleading.